# GigyaSwift login method not opening FacebookWrapper

Tags: ios, swift, gigya

I just started using the new GigyaSwift SDK and i'm trying to implement facebook social login on an existing project. However, when i try to login using facebook, i get an error:

> Fatal error: [facebook] can't login with WebView, install related sdk.

I have imported the SDK and wrappers in my project, and installed the FBSDK pods.
This is my code:

```
Gigya.sharedInstance().login(with: .facebook, viewController: self, completion: { (res) in
            debugPrint(res)
})
```

These are the fields i have inputted into my plist.

```
<key>GigyaApiDomain</key>
    <string>REDACTED</string>
    <key>GigyaApiKey</key>
    <string>REDACTED</string>

<key>FacebookDisplayName</key>
<string>REDACTED</string>
<key>FacebookAppID</key>
<string>REDACTED</string>

<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
    <string>fbapi</string>
    <string>fb-messenger-share-api</string>
    <string>fbauth2</string>
    <string>fbshareextension</string>
</array>

<key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
        <array>
            <string>fbAPP ID HERE</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
</array>
```

I have tried to implement this on a new project and i was able to get it to work. I have tried to copy the settings of the new project to my existing one but that didn't work. A possible cause i have found is that the FacebookWrapper is not executing on login. Has anyone encountered this scenario and is there a fix for it?

EDIT: As requested by @Sagi Shmuel  , here is the print result of my facebook wrapper with redacted names.

> ([REDACTED].FacebookWrapper) $R0 = 0x00006000002a4d00 {
>   ObjectiveC.NSObject = {
>       isa = [REDACTED].FacebookWrapper   }   completionHandler = 0x000000010540f4e0 [REDACTED]`closure #1
>   (Swift.Optional>,
>   Swift.Optional) -> () in variable initialization
>   expression of [REDACTED].FacebookWrapper.(completionHandler in
>   _D4653B6ACC181DF040059B860A43FAE8) : (Swift.Optional>,
>   Swift.Optional) -> () at FacebookWrapper.swift:16
>   clientID = nil   defaultReadPermissions = 1 value {
>       [0] = "email"   }   fbLogin.storage = nil

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's happened because the `GigyaSwift SDK` not found the `FacebookWrapper.swift` file.

Make sure you install `Facebook SDK` and add `FacebookWrapper.swift` file your project and.

Comment: Hi @Sagi, I have installed both FBSDKLoginKit and FBSDKCoreKit pods in my project, and added FacebookWrapper.swift to compile sources. I was able to make facebook login work in a new project and i followed the same steps on my existing one so i'm really not sure why its not working in the existing one

Comment: For starter go to you **Build Phases** and check if `FacebookWrapper.swift` has included.
Also what your bundle name?
and run this code and give me the result: 
`let facebookWrapper = FacebookWrapper()
print(facebookWrapper)`

Comment: Yes, there my FacebookWrapper.swift is included in my `Build Phases Compile Sources`. I'm afraid i cannot give my bundle name since there is some information i cannot give out. I have edited my post with the print statement of facebook wrapper. Thanks

Comment: In your logs you have something like that's: `[SocialProvidersManager]: [facebook] save factory`?

Comment: or `facebook not extend to ProviderWrapperProtocol`?

Comment: No, my project isn't logging that. It is only logging the error OR the `[ProvidersLoginWrapper: 0x600003c5ad00]: Log redirect url:` if i use the socialLoginWith method instead of the login method

Comment: It's look like the sdk not found the `FacebookWrapper.swift`, please go to your info.plist and check if the `Bundle name` is equal to `[REDACTED]` you getting out from `print(facebookWrapper)`.

Comment: Omg. I changed the product name and it worked!! Thank you so much! I've been working on this for so long :D

Answer (score 3):

Suggest checking few things:

1. Product name - Having space in between can lead to this as well incase you have Gigya Swift SDK version lower to 1.1.1
   Say `GigyaDemoApp` -> `Gigya Demo App`.
   Try changing to your product name without space `GigyaDemoApp` like this.
2. Try upgrading your Gigya Swift SDK to `Swift SDK Core Framework 1.1.1 (Latest)`
   Above space issue been fixed in this version as they introduced a way to register wrapper files explicitly.

```
let gigya = Gigya.sharedInstance(UserHost.self)
gigya.registerSocialProvider(of: .facebook, wrapper: FacebookWrapper())
gigya.registerSocialProvider(of: .google, wrapper: GoogleWrapper())
gigya.registerSocialProvider(of: .apple, wrapper: AppleSignInWrapper())
```

Hope this helps!